# What is the red confetti for on my nearby PokeStop?

Tags: pokemon-go

What is the red confetti for on my nearby PokeStop?  It appears to have confetti flying around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an active [Lure Module](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Lure_Module) on the Pokestop. This has been activated by another player and will attract more Pokemon.